# ActiveAdmin markdown editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simplemde

Hi I want to add MD editor to my admin panel.
I tried with: https://github.com/ypylypenko/activeadmin_simplemde

but it does not render markdown correctly:
[image]

I do not know why, no errors in console.
My app use Ruby 2.7.2, Rails 6.0.3, activeadmin 2.8.0

Is there any better markdown editor for activeadmin or how can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like you didn't import the CSS and/or load them (e.g. run webpack?)

Comment: See also: https://github.com/ypylypenko/activeadmin_simplemde/issues/4 (!!) (It looks like the files were renamed, but a new version was never released, so you need to import the old filenames: https://github.com/ypylypenko/activeadmin_simplemde/blob/173cb0c08bbf99d27f453d5d1c50a12f69babf94/README.md)

Comment: I saw this, I am adding this gem from GitHub not from Rubygems

Comment: My point stands that you're not loading the CSS. Check that webpack is running (assuming that's how your rails application is set up??) and look for any errors.

Comment: I am not using webpack this app is in API mode

Comment: Have you looked whether the CSS is being loaded on the page? Have you checked whether the `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss` file is being evaluated at all? Have you inspected the element to see if styles are being overridden, e.g. if you've defined something with `!important` elsewhere in the CSS?

Comment: I have checked and all CSS are loaded correctly

Comment: ok after looking at what is being written to the database it is not a problem with the editor per se, I guess the result is not a valid markdown, "\r" is added before every "\n"

Comment: The problem is that the formatted text, in the grey box on the right, isn't getting rendered in the complete/correct "pretty" way. I wouldn't expect anything to be wrong *in the database*, no. If "all the CSS is loaded correctly", then why doesn't it look normal? Right click the text, select "inspect", and have a look at what styles are being applied. It "should" be using the styles defined here: https://github.com/ypylypenko/activeadmin_simplemde/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/simplemde.css#L7

Comment: all css are loaded, imo problem is with this carriage return char, when I manually removed it in devtools, formatted text renders correctly